# Casting list to listview that was generated from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

**Quick Info**

I am following one of the example videos on Lynda.com titled App Development with Local Storage. I have the exercise files but I am attempting to follow using my own setup.

**DB Setup**

A database is being created then all the data is being populated to the `List` interface of `DataItem` element using the `Cursor` Object. The `DataItem` is a model class that implement `Parcelable` and is used to model the SQL data using setters and getters. This is my limited understanding of the class which may be the cause of the problem.

**Current Setup**

I created a new Activity from the standard Navigation Drawer, and I am attempting to display the database (which is being created correctly, and tested) to a `list_view` located in `content_main.xml`.

**Question**

My problem lies is not knowing exactly what to include within the `ArrayAdapter`.

```
listFromDB = maSource.getAllItems();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
               (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, **?listFromDB?**); 

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

As I mentioned, `listFromDB` is of type list that includes the DB. Outputting it into logcat will result in 4 columns and 2 rows.

> 12-29 00:36:40.977 6326-6326/? D/dbinfo:
>   [DataItem{accountId='6d8bb011-bd9a-4c71-b4c7-2ddaa5fe6fce',
>   accountName='Row 1', description='Info About Row 1', balance=1903.59},
>   DataItem{accountId='b6d08c68-d41d-4821-b901-23e7f38cebd9',
>   accountName='Row 2', description='Info About Row 2', balance=41.28}]
>
> [ 12-29 00:36:41.097  6326: 6326 D/         ]
>
> HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7aba1b0, tid 6326

Comment: you have to create custom adapter to show list data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Divyesh I found a solution to my problem.

---

Creating a custom ArrayAdapter did the trick:

1. Create an additional layout view to include required widgets. 3 TextViews were created in my case under `data_view.xml`
2. A list parser was created to extract the data from each row that is found inside the database and constructed as `DataItem` into `listFromDB`.
3. The custom adapter was then defined which extends `ArrayAdapter` and assign the values to the TextViews after the `data_view.xml` has been inflated.
4. Lastly, the new custom adapter was used in `MainActivity` and items from the list were assigned to the appropriate TextViews

The following is a sample of the steps mentioned above to which I am going to refactor later on.

**data_view.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accountName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Account Name" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Description" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/balance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Balance" />
```

**ListParser**

```
public class ListParser {
    public String accountName;
    public String description;
    public String balance;

    public ListParser(String accountName, String description, String balance) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.description = description;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class AccountAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListParser> {
    public AccountAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListParser> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView accountName;
        TextView description;
        TextView balance;

        public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
             accountName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.accountName);
             description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
             balance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.balance);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        ListParser user = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.account_view, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView accountName = viewHolder.accountName;
        TextView description = viewHolder.description;
        TextView balance = viewHolder.balance;
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        accountName.setText(user.accountName);
        description.setText(user.description);
        balance.setText(user.balance);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity** (Single Row)

```
ArrayList<ListParser> arrayOfListParsers = new ArrayList<ListParser>();
AccountAdapter adapter = new AccountAdapter(this, arrayOfListParsers);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

ListParser newUser = new ListParser(String.valueOf(listFromDB.get(0).getaccountName()), String.valueOf(listFromDB.get(0).getDescription()), String.valueOf(listFromDB.get(0).getBalance()));
adapter.add(newUser);
```

---

More work needs to be done to the `MainActivity` Class, but this was just a test run.

<sub>Additional Credit: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView</sub>

Comment: You should look into using `ViewHolder Pattern` so that you don't do the view lookup for each `getView()` call. I added it to the code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I went ahead and updated my Adapter to View Holder and was about to update my answer, then I realized you have already done it. Thanks.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce We had the same thing, except you added `public ViewHolder(View view){...}` causing `counterView` not to be recognized.

Comment: It was simply IntelliJ pointing out that the variable cannot be resolved, I didn't run the code with the previous error. I'll include the recent edit when I get home and update.

Comment: no, I'm glad you mentioned it, I did the edit on the fly, I've since fixed it accordingly :)

Comment: That works. I haven't tested it on a real device but even on the emulator it's much faster. Thank you for mentioning the `View Holder`